# How is delete operator working in my code?

Tags: c++, memory-management

If `delete` deallocate  memory then why do first two element are being reset to their initial garbage value and the rest are not? After I delete the pointer I am getting unusual output. Please explain how it works and why I am getting such output.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *q = new int[10];
    int *r;
    r=q;
    printf("%d %d\n",*r,*(r+1));

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        q[i]=100;

    delete[] q;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout<<"r="<<*(r+i)<<"   ";
        cout<<"q="<<*(q+i)<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is given below:

> 8389928 8388800 r=8389928   q=8389928 r=8388800   q=8388800 r=100
>   q=100 r=100   q=100 r=100   q=100 r=100   q=100 r=100   q=100 r=100
>   q=100 r=100   q=100 r=100   q=100

Comment: What output are you *expecting* after `delete`?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what "delete" does.

Comment: "Why is delete operator not working in my code?"  The `delete[]` operator is working in your code.  Your code has bugs (via undefined behavior).  Remove the bugs.  C++ is not a nanny language, the onus is on the programmer not to misuse the language.

Answer (score 8):

Your code has Undefined Behaviour (which means it's buggy and literally anything can happen), for several reasons.

1. You're reading uninitialised memory by printing `*r` and `*(r+1)` before anything is assigned to these objects. `new int[]` Does not initialise the allocated memory in any way: you must assign values before you can read from it.

   BTW, note that `*(r+1)` is more commonly written as `r[1]`.
2. (After question edit, this part no longer applies) You've allocated memory with `new []`, but you're deallocating it with `delete`. `new[]` must always be paired with `delete[]` (and `new` with `delete`).
3. You're accessing memory which you no longer own by dereferencing `r` and `q` after deleting the memory pointed to by `q` (and `r`) (even if you had used the correct `delete[] q;`). Once you free memory, you are no longer allowed to access its contents.

Comment: It's amazing how many serious bugs can fit in such a short program.